# unordered_map with referenced key

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, unordered-map

I have something wrong with the new C++ unordered_map: I would like to use the `operator[]` with a `const` key, but I get rejected.

I cannot give the whole code, but I can simplify my problem like this:

```
#include <unordered_map>

class A {
    public:
        A();
};

class B {
    public:
        B();
};

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::unordered_map<A &, B> myMap;
    A a;
    const A &ar = a;
    B b;
    myMap[ar] = b;
}
```

The output of the compiler is a bit long, but ends with:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/hashtable_policy.h:537:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const A’ to ‘A&’
```

I use a `const A &` because, in my code, some method give it to me as is.  And, by the way, the key should be const.  I have tried a `std::unordered_map<const A &, B> myMap;` instead, but it does not work either.

I use gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5), with the `-std=c++0x` flag.

Could you please tell me why this is forbidden?  I must say I do not understand the reason.

Many thanks (and please excuse me if the question is stupid...).

Comment: *"I cannot give the whole code, but I can simplify my problem like this"* +1, because that's exactly what we want you to do when asking a question, try to reduce it to the smallest possible example where the problem is still existent.

Comment: Thank you again to the whole community.  I had many accurate and useful answers in no time.  Just great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is that `operator[]` is specified as follows (note that the same holds for just `std::map`):

```
Value& operator[](Key const& k);
```

In your case, `Key` is `A&`, so this expands to:

```
B& operator[](A& const& k);
```

And since references-to-references are invalid and the top-level reference is dropped when created through typedefs or template parameters, you get just:

```
B& operator[](A&);
```

Which can't handle an `A const&` argument.

In general, I'd advise against using a mutable reference as the key, since mutable keys are a good source for errors.

Comment: Is that so?  Many thanks for the answer.  I did not know this.  These technicalities still are a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0):

Using a reference as a key is a Bad Idea: It is bound to cause problems because the life-time of the map and the keys aren't aligned. The key type of your map of references is `T&` (well, there is a `const` added at the end but it would be illegal). Trying to bind a `T const&` to a `T&` doesn't work. Hence, you can't use `T const&` to look-up in a map using `T&` as a key.

There are other things which won't work. You should not try to use a map with a key of `T&` (or `T*` for that matter): use values as keys!

Comment: Not the map is const, but the key is.

Comment: @Xeo: Right. You also can't bind a `T const&` to a `T&` which is the key type attempted to be used here (even assuming everything else in the map works with references which it does not).

Comment: Many thanks too.  I now understand why this map was actually a conceptual flaw.  I will change it right away.